# Highcharts, Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I copy and pasted code from the beginning Highcharts tutorial online but still nothing shows up in my browser. I'm new to coding and am looking for some help please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- DEV -->
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script scr="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>
<!-- /DEV -->
<title>highcharts</title>

<script>
$(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
type: 'bar'
},
title: {
text: 'Fruit Consumption'
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Fruit eaten'
}
},
series: [{
name: 'Jane',
data: [1, 0, 4]
}, {
name: 'John',
data: [5, 7, 3]
}]
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you also copied the addentional `*.js` files to your disk?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
<script scr="highcharts.js"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at this forever, yet couldn't see that.